HTML5 and CSS grid - Can't get it to fit the content
It's been a loong time since I did HTML and CSS, and I'm playing around with grid-layout, but can't get it to work.
I have made a burger menu, that, when I click it, should toggle the display attribute and show the menu  tag. This works, but because the grid is also inside a  element, the content of the grid is not filling the whole parent element, just a part of it.
Also, I would like the LinkedIn and WhatsApp icon to be in the lower right corner of the blue rectangle. I have tried with divs and position, but that ruined a lot and had a weird behaviour.
Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?


function nav_burger(burger) {
  burger.classList.toggle("morph");
  var e = document.getElementById("navigation");
  if (e.style.display === "none") {
    e.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    e.style.display = "none";
  }
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

div#scaffold_screen {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}


/* scl = scaffold container left */

div#scr {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  /*  width: 66%; */
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 15px;
}


/* scr = scaffold container right */

div#scl {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  /*  width: 34%; */
  padding: 30px 15px 30px 30px;
}


/* scc = scaffold content container */

div.scc {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/** GRID LAYOUT **/

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
  /**  grid-column-gap: 20px; **/
  /** changed to gap since deprecated **/
  /**  column-gap: 20px; **/
  gap: 20px;
  /** horizontal and vertical gap **/
  padding: 0px;
}


/** it divides the screen in 14, counting up the grids auto shifting lines **/

.gridbox-1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
  border: 0px solid #00ff00;
}

.gridbox-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
  border: 0px solid #ffff00;
}

.gridbox-3 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.gridbox-4 {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.gridbox-5 {
  grid-column: span 5;
}

.gridbox-6 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.gridbox-7 {
  grid-column: span 7;
}

.gridbox-8 {
  grid-column: span 8;
  border: 0px solid #0ffff0;
}

.gridbox-9 {
  grid-column: span 9;
}

.gridbox-10 {
  grid-column: span 10;
  border: 0px solid #00ffff;
}

.gridbox-11 {
  grid-column: span 11;
}

.gridbox-12 {
  grid-column: span 12;
}

.gridbox-13 {
  grid-column: span 13;
}

.gridbox-14 {
  grid-column: span 14;
  border: 0px solid #00ff00;
}


/** LOGO **/


/*  logo container */

div#logo {
  font-family: 'Red Hat Text';
  font-size: 34pt;
  letter-spacing: 1.8pt;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 30px;
}


/* logo color 1 */

span.logo_c1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* logo color 2 */

span.logo_c2 {
  color: #06d6a0;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/** NAVIGATION **/

div#navigation_icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 25px 30px 0px 0px;
}


/** navgivation burger icon **/

div.burgerbar1,
div.burgerbar2,
div.burgerbar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.morph .burgerbar1 {
  transform: translate(0, 11px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.morph .burgerbar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.morph .burgerbar3 {
  transform: translate(0, -11px) rotate(45deg);
}

nav#navigation {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: none;
  font-size: 40pt;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

nav#navigation p {
  letter-spacing: 1.1pt;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 80px;
}

nav#navigation p.description {
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #efefef;
  padding: 10px 0px 50px 90px;
}

nav#navigation p a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav#navigation p a:hover {
  color: #06d6a0;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/** HEADER TAGS **/

h1 {
  font-size: 34pt;
  font-family: 'Red Hat Text';
  margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
}
<div id="scaffold_screen">
  <div id="scl">
    <div class="scc" style="background-color: #003388;">
      <div class="grid">

        <div class="gridbox-13">
          <div id="logo"><span class="logo_c1">my website</span><span class="logo_c2">.</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gridbox-1">
          <div id="navigation_icon" onclick="nav_burger(this)">
            <div class="burgerbar1"></div>
            <div class="burgerbar2"></div>
            <div class="burgerbar3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <nav id="navigation" style="display: none; border: 0px solid #ff0000;">
          <div class="gridbox-14">
            <p><a href="#">my website.</a></p>
            <p class="description">very looong text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="gridbox-14">
            <p><a href="#">some day we like</a></p>
            <p class="description">a very looong text, but even longer</p>
          </div>
          <div class="gridbox-14">
            <p><a href="#">discover</a></p>
            <p class="description">tired of long texts</p>
          </div>
          <div class="gridbox-14">
            <p><a href="#">just</a></p>
            <p class="description">heeelp</p>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="gridbox-14">
          <p style="padding: 0px 30px 30px 0px; text-align: right;"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 15pt;"></i> &nbsp; <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 15pt;"></i></p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="scr" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="scc">
      <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-image: url('images/front/a.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



----- The CSS ------
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

div#scaffold_screen {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

/* scl = scaffold container left */
div#scr {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
/*  width: 66%; */
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 15px;
}

/* scr = scaffold container right */
div#scl {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
/*  width: 34%; */
  padding: 30px 15px 30px 30px;
}


/* scc = scaffold content container */
div.scc {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/** GRID LAYOUT **/
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
/**  grid-column-gap: 20px; **/ /** changed to gap since deprecated **/
/**  column-gap: 20px; **/
  gap: 20px; /** horizontal and vertical gap **/
  padding: 0px;
}

/** it divides the screen in 14, counting up the grids auto shifting lines **/
.gridbox-1  { grid-column: span 1; border: 0px solid #00ff00; }
.gridbox-2  { grid-column: span 2; border: 0px solid #ffff00;  }
.gridbox-3  { grid-column: span 3; }
.gridbox-4  { grid-column: span 4; }
.gridbox-5  { grid-column: span 5; }
.gridbox-6  { grid-column: span 6; }
.gridbox-7  { grid-column: span 7; }
.gridbox-8  { grid-column: span 8; border: 0px solid #0ffff0;}
.gridbox-9  { grid-column: span 9; }
.gridbox-10 { grid-column: span 10; border: 0px solid #00ffff;}
.gridbox-11 { grid-column: span 11; }
.gridbox-12 { grid-column: span 12; }
.gridbox-13 { grid-column: span 13; }
.gridbox-14 { grid-column: span 14; border: 0px solid #00ff00; }
  
  
/** LOGO **/
  
/*  logo container */
div#logo {
  font-family: 'Red Hat Text';
  font-size: 34pt;
  letter-spacing: 1.8pt;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 30px;
}

/* logo color 1 */
span.logo_c1 { color: #ffffff; }

/* logo color 2 */
span.logo_c2 { color: #06d6a0; font-weight: bold; }


/** NAVIGATION **/

div#navigation_icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 25px 30px 0px 0px;
}

/** navgivation burger icon **/
div.burgerbar1, div.burgerbar2, div.burgerbar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: 0.4s; 
}

.morph .burgerbar1 { transform: translate(0, 11px) rotate(-45deg); }
.morph .burgerbar2 { opacity: 0; }
.morph .burgerbar3 { transform: translate(0, -11px) rotate(45deg); }

nav#navigation {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: none;
  font-size: 40pt;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

nav#navigation p { letter-spacing: 1.1pt; margin-top: -20px; padding: 10px 0px 0px 80px; }
nav#navigation p.description { font-size: 14pt; font-style: italic; color: #efefef; padding: 10px 0px 50px 90px; }
nav#navigation p a { color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; }
nav#navigation p a:hover { color: #06d6a0; text-decoration: none; }



/** HEADER TAGS **/
h1 { font-size: 34pt; font-family: 'Red Hat Text'; margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px; }

----- The HTML -----
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- fontawesome.com -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/46d80123d5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<style type="text/css">
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alexandria&family=Anek+Latin&family=Inter&family=M+PLUS+1&family=Montserrat&family=Noto+Sans+Display&family=Noto+Serif+Display&family=Open+Sans&family=Quicksand&family=Red+Hat+Display&family=Red+Hat+Text&family=Source+Serif+4:opsz@8..60&display=swap');
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">

<title>my website</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="scaffold_screen">
  <div id="scl">
    <div class="scc" style="background-color: #003388;">
      <div class="grid">

        <div class="gridbox-13"><div id="logo"><span class="logo_c1">my website</span><span class="logo_c2">.</span></div></div>
        <div class="gridbox-1">
          <div id="navigation_icon" onclick="nav_burger(this)">
            <div class="burgerbar1"></div>
            <div class="burgerbar2"></div>
            <div class="burgerbar3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <nav id="navigation" style="display: none; border: 0px solid #ff0000;">
          <div class="gridbox-14"><p><a href="#">my website.</a></p><p class="description">very looong text</p></div>
          <div class="gridbox-14"><p><a href="#">some day we like</a></p><p class="description">a very looong text, but even longer</p></div>
          <div class="gridbox-14"><p><a href="#">discover</a></p><p class="description">tired of long texts</p></div>
          <div class="gridbox-14"><p><a href="#">just</a></p><p class="description">heeelp</p></div>
        </nav>

        <div class="gridbox-14"><p style="padding: 0px 30px 30px 0px; text-align: right;"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 15pt;"></i> &nbsp; <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 15pt;"></i></p></div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="scr" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="scc">
      <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-image: url('images/front/a.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->

<script>
  function nav_burger(burger) {
    burger.classList.toggle("morph");
    var e = document.getElementById("navigation");
    if (e.style.display === "none") {
      e.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      e.style.display = "none";
    }
  } 
</script>

  </body>
</html>


I'm on mobile and using CodePen but I think I know what's going on and I've got a solution for you,
Grid Layout
The issue with your grid not filling the parent container likely comes from how the container is styled and how the grid itself is being handled. The container of the grid, which is .scc, is taking the full width and height, but we need to ensure that the grid inside it also stretches fully.
You can add the following CSS to ensure that the grid takes up the full height of the parent:
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%; /* Ensure grid takes full height */
}

This should ensure that the grid expands fully within the parent container.
Icon Position
The issue with positioning the icons can be handled by using position: absolute on the element that contains the icons, and setting its parent as position: relative to control the positioning within that parent. Here’s how to adjust it:
First, wrap the icons in a container if they aren't already. Then, use the following CSS:
/* Parent container */
div.scc {
  position: relative; /* Establish this container as the reference point */
}

/* Icon container */
div.icon-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px; /* Distance from bottom */
  right: 20px;  /* Distance from right */
  text-align: right; /* Align icons within the container */
}

.icon-container i {
  font-size: 15pt;
  color: #ffffff;
}

Update your HTML accordingly:
<div class="icon-container">
  <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i> &nbsp;
  <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
</div>

This will position the icons 20px from the bottom-right corner of the .scc container.
Recap

Add height: 100% to the grid to ensure it fills the parent container.

Use position: absolute to position the LinkedIn and WhatsApp icons at the bottom-right corner.


Other Considerations

Ensure that your div#scaffold_screen is taking up the full width and height of the viewport if it's not already.

You might want to ensure that overflow is handled correctly, especially for the grid's container, to prevent clipping or unwanted scrollbars.



Hi Claykom
It seems something worked with the grid, but the  tag still doesn't use the full width, so the text is squeezed to multiple lines.
I had tried to mix and match the position and grid, but it didn't work out well. Adding your code just moved them to the box on the right with the trees in the bottom right. It seems that if position is used, it ignores grids.

Just to clarify,  the grid is now taking up the correct space but the nav tag is being reduced?The Icons moved to the bottom right of the screen or the bottom right of the wrong box?

It seems so, when I use a Firefox plugin to outline the block elements.
And yes, the  tag is being reduced. I've tried different things, also putting the  inside the grid div, but doesn't work. If I set a specific width eg. 800px it works, but that wont work when I should make it responsive.
Yes the icons moved to the bottom right side, but the wrong box; the box to the right.

Sorry, I'm going to try again a bit later I don't have the time and this isn't exactly my expertise so maybe someone else can be of more use than myself.

I played around with it some more, and got it working.
The  tag worked with: style="width: 100vw;" and is now using the full width of it's parent element.
I got the icons moved to the right position using: style="position: relative;" on the  containing the icons, and style="osition: absolute;"> on th  tag used to style it.
Thank you for helping! You pointed me in the right direction!

Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

Thanks for letting me know, this was my answer I wrote the code and tested it in CodePen. I see a lot of generative ai, I actually use it in my applications at work. I simply answered in the same way and provide a recap/consideration section to make it easily digestible and to help stimulate your thoughts process so you can be original. The reason my considerations vague is because I hadn't tested it on  a computer.

You can also try this
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 14) - 20px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

